# WiX4 bootstrapper: Right way to define boolean command line argument

Tags: wix, bundle, burn, wix4

I'm aimed at setting an argument like `/DefaultMode`, just a shash + name of a command, without passing a value like `DefaultMode=1`. I motivated by default wix arguments like: `/install | /repair | /uninstall`.

**case 1:**
`<Variable Name="/DefaultMode" bal:Overridable="yes" Value="NotSet" Type="string" />`
returns an error:
`error WIX0014: The Variable/@Name attribute's value, '/DefaultMode  ', is not a legal identifier. Identifiers may contain ASCII characters A-Z, a-z, digits, underscores (_), or periods (.). Every identifier  must begin with either a letter or an underscore.`

**case 2:**
`<Variable Name="DefaultMode" bal:Overridable="yes" Value="NotSet" Type="string" />`
unfortunatelly but passing argument `.\Bundle.exe DefaultMode` equals to `Variable: DefaultMode = NotSet`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a custom BoostrapperApplication to process your custom command-line. The standard BoostrapperApplication handles setting variables on the command-line like `DefaultMode=1`.